# Cannot "Query" hyperledger-fabric, error code -32003

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I have a working Hyperledger-Fabric environment, running locally on my Mac. I setup the `chaincode_example02` code, but the `Query` REST call isn't working. I trying doing a `deploy` and `invoke` and both of those calls work. I am using Postman to send the REST calls.

`Query`:

```
    {
      "jsonrpc": "2.0",
      "method": "query",
      "params": {
        "type": 1,
        "chaincodeID": {
        "name": "mycc",
        "path": "/tmp/hyperledger-BR/example0/gopath/src/github.com/chaincode_example02/chaincode_example02"
     },
        "ctorMsg": {
          "function": "query",
          "args": ["b"]
        }
      },
      "id": 0
    }
```

Serverside Error:

> Error starting Simple chaincode: Error handling message:
>   [ef980ad7-94c8-4ec9-92f4-3ebdd47e4321]Chaincode handler FSM cannot
>   handle message (RANGE_QUERY_STATE) with payload size (10) while in
>   state: ready

Postman Returned Error:

> {   "jsonrpc": "2.0",   "error": {
>       "code": -32003,
>       "message": "Query failure",
>       "data": "Error when querying chaincode: Error:Failed to execute transaction or query(Timeout expired while executing transaction)"
>   },   "id": 0 }

I have been digging online, but I have no idea why this is happening. Any clue as to why this is happening?

Comment: If you follow [this document](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Setup/Chaincode-setup/#chaincode-deploy-via-cli-and-rest)
You need to make sure that the transaction went through. I found sometimes even it returns the success response but the transaction fails.
Please double check the log when you deploy the chaincode. I believe there was something wrong.
Also, path is not necessary on the query. only name is enough because name(mycc) is the reference for deployed chaincode

Comment: @PunNeng thanks for the response! I removed the path from the request JSON. However, I cannot find the log under /var/log would it be in another place that I'm not aware of?

Comment: it should be displayed in terminal if you enable `CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG` when you start a peer.
and another thing you might need to check is how you get docker daemon running. The docker native for mac starts the docker remote api with sock file then you might need to mount /var/run/docker.sock into you docker container

Comment: @PunNeng Oh I see, yes that is what I'm doing with this instance and the above error is what displays on the terminal.

Comment: what about after deploying the chaincode? Basically, after deploying, Invoke function will be executed then it stores the transaction. what i was wondering is deploying might went through but the transaction might not. So I just want to make sure that all operation went through

Comment: You're absolutely right @PunNeng when I do a deploy or invoke, I get the following error, ERRO : [618b2880]Transaction execution failed. Sending ERROR. But the response on Postman says "Ok"

Comment: ok then you should see more details why the transaction execution failed if you look around what displayed in the terminal. Next I'd like you to make sure that your machine can talk to the docker containers through the docker daemon and then set CORE_VM_ENPOINT correctly with the docker daemon endpoint. you are on mac then the docker daemon endpoint is unix:///var/run/docker.sock by default then set this a the value of CORE_VM_ENPOINT and dont forget to mount the endpoint into the docker container. That should make it executes propperly.